# Eclipse file saved as garbage

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I recently had an eclipse crash on Ubuntu 12.04. After I had restarted, the file that I had been editing was now filled with random Unicode characters. Is there anyway to get the original file contents back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the file from the context menu and choose "Replace With -> Local History".  You'll see a view populated with any previous versions of the file that have been saved by Eclipse.  The most recent version should be in good condition, but it may not have the changes you were making when Eclipse crashed.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant1 Thanks so much

Comment: life saver. this is an absolutely crazy eclipse bug.